# Mysql select record saved 1 month ago or the older one if none found

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I got a small stat table similar to :

```
+----+----------+-------+------------+-------------+
| id | stat_key | value | created_at | customer_id |
+----+----------+-------+------------+-------------+
```

Each day, a cron perform some calculation and saves stat for each customer.

Now I want to retrieve the stat from 30 days ago, or if the customer is new, the older stat available as long as it's less than 30 days ago.

So I tried to perform the following query, but for customers older than 30 days, it's always the older stat of all time that is returned :

```
SELECT * 
FROM stat_table 
WHERE customer_id = 1 AND stat_key = 'some_key' 
HAVING (DATE(created_at) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
       OR DATE(created_at) = DATE(MIN(created_at)));
```

Is there a way to perfom this ? "Give me the stat from 30 days ago, and if not found, the older one you can find"

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `limit` with an `order by` to retrieve the oldest row that's not more than 30 days old:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    stat_table 
WHERE   customer_id = 1 
        AND stat_key = 'some_key' 
        AND created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
ORDER BY
        created_at
LIMIT   1
```

Comment: It should be `AND created_at < NOW()...` or didn't I have enough coffee yet?

Comment: @tombom: The row should be at most 30 days old.  You haven't had enough coffee yet :)